# Area moment of inertia of regular $n$-gons over polygon center $O$

Tags: homework-and-exercises, rotational-dynamics, geometry, moment-of-inertia, rigid-body-dynamics

Is it possible to consider the regular polygons ($n$-gons) as deformed circles and use a [pseudo-polar coordinate system](http://www.google.com/#q=pseudo-polar+coordinate+system) to calculate their moment of inertia over its center $O$. Inasmuch as I know (I am a solid mechanics beginner), we can find the area moment of inertia $J_O$ of the circle $C(O,R)$ considering a circular disk of thickness $dr$.

Can I apply the same to regular polygons, namely if their area is equal to:

$$A = \frac{nr^2}{2 \sin{(2 \pi / n})}$$

then the differential area element $dA$ will be equal to the area of the outer polygon with radius $r+dr$ minus the area of the inside one of radius $r$:

$$dA  = A(r+dr) - A(r) = \frac{n}{2 \sin{(2\pi/n})}dr (2r+dr)$$

so the moment of inertia at the center O of the solid polygon can be calculated as:

$$J_O = \int^R_0 r^2 dA = \int^R_0 r^2  \frac{n}{2 \sin{(2\pi/n})}dr (2r+dr)$$

where $R$ is the radius of the polygon (the distance between its center and its vertices).

Considering the above $J_O$ tends to be equal to the one of the perfect circle:

$$\lim_{n \to +\infty} J_O = \pi r^4 / 4$$

Are my claims right?

Answer (score 1):

Assumption: Just to make things explicit, I am assuming (as are you) that the objects you're considering have a constant mass per unit area.

1. The moment of inertia for a uniform disc (circle filled in) is $ \int_0^R r^2 2 \pi r dr = \frac{\pi}{2} R^4$. So **if** I'm interpreting your last formula correctly, your answer seems to be off by a factor of $2$. I think the problem is in your formula for the area of a polygon. Take the limit of large $n$ and you're off from the area of a circle by the same factor of $2$.
2. Your use of the expression for $dA$ to compute the moment of inertia confuses me. All the infinitesimal elements of mass in your $dA$ are not at the same distance from the center of the polygon. So you can't just multiply them by $r^2$ to get the moment of inertia (MI) for that infinitesimal element. *However, even if your formula for an n-gon is wrong, such approximations should work in the limit of large $n$, and so could give you the correct answer for a disc.*

A simpler way to find the MI for a polygon is to split it up as a bunch of isoceles triangles rotating around their "apex". The moment of inertia of each such triangle (with an apex angle of $\theta$ is quite easy to calculate:
$$I_{\Delta(\theta)} = \int_0^{R\, \cos \frac{\theta}{2}} \; dr \; 2 r \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \; r^2 = \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \frac{1}{2} {\left[ R\, \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \right]}^4$$
To find the moment of inertia of an n-gon, you multiply by $n$ the MI of one triangle of apex angle $\frac{2 \pi}{n}$. Then you can take the limit $n \rightarrow \infty$ or $\theta \rightarrow 0$.
$$ \lim_{\theta \rightarrow 0} \frac{2 \pi}{\theta} \sin \left(\frac{\theta}{2} \right) \frac{1}{2} {\left[ R\, \cos \frac{\theta}{2} \right]}^4 = \frac{\pi}{2} R^4$$
since for small $\alpha$ $\sin(\alpha) \approx \alpha$ and $\cos(\alpha) \approx 1$ to linear order in $\alpha$.

---

A comment about your calculation: 
 $dA = A(r+dr) - A(r) = dr \,(2r + dr) \cong 2r \, dr$ since we only care about the linear order in $dr$, which is assumed to be infinitesimal.